# Why does sharpdevelop use .content for labels while visual studio uses .text even though they're both c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharpdevelop

I use visual studio at work but don't have it on my home computer, so I downloaded SharpDevelop. I recently found out visual studio is free for students anyway so I'll be using that from now on. However, while using SharpDevelop, I noticed that when you create a `Label` via the designer, the property that controls the text in that `Label` is not called `Text` like it is in visual studio, but I assumed it would be since they are both c#.

My understanding is that the designer is just a GUI version of XML code, and that it creates the XML code for you. If you navigate to that XML file, I thought maybe the name of that property was arbitrary and you could change it there, but that didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, Visual Studio Community (which have almost all the functionality of VS Pro) is free even for small company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct that they are both c#, but probably one is `WinForms` and another is [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). The designer use [XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295302.aspx) that is an XML-based markup language developed by Microsoft. Instead of a `Text` property, the `Label` has a `Content` property, The reason for that is that the `Label` can host any kind of control directly inside of it, instead of just text. This content can be a string as well.